# facebook login button does not work in jsf page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, facebook-login

Hi everyone im new to JSF , and im making a web application , so i wanted to add the  facebook login functionality , i added all the code  but when i run the application and when i push the facebook login button this message appears : "Error Parsing /FacebookLogin.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 94] The prefix "fb" for element "fb:login-button" is not bound." 
I changed the value of "Param-value" to "Production" but it still not working , i even changed the body tag to a normal one instead of  but the problems persist. If anyone knows the solution let me know and Thanx :)

Comment: "The prefix isn't bound" is a pretty straightforward message: you need to declare the "fb" prefix at the top of the xhtml page, along  with the other prefixes you (probably) already have there ("f","h" etc)

Comment: thank youu kolossus ^^  i declared the fb prefix and  it works :)))